# Как получить значение переменной из Js в Python

Tags: javascript, python, html

как я могу использовать переменную из JS использовать в питоне?

код в app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

html + Js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="number" id="input-id" />
    <button onclick="getValue()">Получить значение</button>
<script>
    function getValue() {
        let input = document.getElementById('input-id')
        let value = input.value
        console.log(value)
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

мне нужно значение переменной value использовать в питоне, но не пойму как это сделать

Comment: HTTP запросом из js отправляете ее на бэкэнд (Python), там обрабатываете.

Comment: а как это сделать?, просто раньше не сталкивался с таким

Comment: Со стороны js - хз, не пишу на нем. На бэкэнде добавляете роут, обрабатывающий GET или POST или другой метод (аналогично вашей функции index, только с параметрами). Если get - обычно параметры передаются внутри самого url или через параметры url. Если post/put/patch, то можно в теле запроса что-то передать.

Answer (score 1):

> Как получить значение переменной из Js в Python

Например отправить это значение запросом на сервер...

```
function getValue() {
   let input = document.getElementById('input-id')
   let value = input.value
   console.log(value)
   fetch('http://mysite.ru?value=' + encodeURIComponent(value))
      .then(_ => console.log('Успешно'))
      .catch(console.log)
}
```